# Partial match between 2 columns and results in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am having 2 columns (A&B) and I want to get in the column C the partial matches of these two columns. For example :

```
A
Lore: Excavator
Lore: Scribe
Athletics: Strong Back
Healing: Medicine
Melee: No Mercy
Insight: Sixth Sense
Melee: Strong Man
Parry: Stage Fighting
Healing: Cure Wounds
Craft: Journeyman
Craft: Master Crafter
Discipline: Courageous
Discipline: Jaded
Linguistics: Accent
Stealth: Living Shadows

B
----
Lore
Healing
Parry
Stealth
Craft

C (Should be)
----
Lore: Excavator
Lore: Scribe
Healing: Medicine
Healing: Cure Wounds
Parry: Stage Fighting
Stealth: Living Shadows
Craft: Journeyman
Craft: Master Crafter
```

ps: This is just a sample list. Normally the A list will have more entries but always the B column will have 5 values

Thank you

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Simpler code for you to try,

```
Sub findMatch()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
k = 1
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To 5
        If InStr(Cells(i, 1), Cells(j, 2)) Then
            Cells(k, 3) = Cells(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it works great:) is it possible to make the macro run automatically the moment Column B gets all 5 entries? Or if one of the entries in Column B changes to refresh automatically the macro (and obviously deleting the previous C column entries?

Comment: Hmm one last question . If , in the original file (not the test) the values of the Column A is a range (D50:D80), the values of the Column B is the range (G50:G54) and the values of the column C should start from H50 to whatever what should I change to the code? Thanks again and sorry for the many questions :(

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2:** This version will automatically update once there are five entries in G50:G54 or one of the entries in that range is changed. Put this in the worksheet code for the sheet the data is on. This code is easily updated to check whatever ranges you want (just change rng1, rng2, or rng3).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng1 = ws.Range("D50:D80")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("G50:G54")
Set rng3 = ws.Range("H50:H80")

If Not Intersect(rng2, Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Application.CountA(rng2) >= 5 Then
        rng3.ClearContents
        For x = rng1.Cells(1, 1).Row To rng1.Cells(1, 1).Row + Application.CountA(rng1) - 1
            For y = rng2.Cells(1, 1).Row To rng2.Cells(1, 1).Row + Application.CountA(rng2) - 1
                If InStr(rng1.Cells(x - rng1.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1).Text, rng2.Cells(y - rng2.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1).Text) Then
                    ws.Cells(Application.CountA(rng3) + rng3.Cells(1, 1).Row, rng3.Cells(1, 1).Column).Formula = rng1.Cells(x - rng1.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1).Text
                End If
            Next y
        Next x
    End If
End If

End Sub
```